# Set alternative python for a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert list such as this

```
l = ['tropical fruit,yogurt,coffee', 'whole milk,whole milk']
```

to something list this

```
[{'tropical fruit',
  'yogurt',
  'coffee'}
  {'whole milk}]
```

Any ideas? I tried to use `[set(word) for word in l]` but it give me a breakdown by a letter and I need it by a word. Please help.

Comment: What's the logic behind  `'whole milk'` getting it's own `set` in the output?

Comment: Do you mean `[set(word.split(",")) for word in l]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   list_values=['tropical fruit,yogurt,coffee', 'whole milk,whole milk']
   [set(values.split(','))for values in list_values]

   #OutPut : [{'coffee', 'tropical fruit', 'yogurt'}, {'whole milk'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a list comprehension and a split.

```
l2 = [set(e.split(",")) for e in l]
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
print("".join(set(l)))
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, but I suspect that this unifies the characters, not the words as asked in the question.